# href link looking for url on local host

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink

I am trying to make a dynamic link so that people using my web app can go to a web page that has additional information. The sites that the link goes to all have the same base url and are differentiated by a unique id at the end of the url (in this case an APN). When the page loads the link looks exactly as it should but when I click it goes to a file that doesn't exist on my desktop.

Here is my code:

```
var template = new InfoTemplate();
                template.setTitle("<b>Parcel</b>");

                template.setContent("<hr>Parcel No: <b>${APN}</b>" +
                    "<hr>Book No: <b>${BOOK}</b>" +
                    "<hr>Page No: <b>${PAGE}</b>" +
                    "<hr>Address: <b>${SitusAddress}</b>" +
                    "<hr>Appraised Value: <b>${Imps}</b> " +
                    "<hr>Year Built: <b>${YearBuilt}</b>" +
                    "<hr> View Assessor's Map: <a href=<b>www.acgov.org/MS/prop/index.aspx?PRINT_PARCEL=${APN}</b></a>" +
                    "<hr><img src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/streetview?size=270x150&location=${SitusAddress}&fov=120&pitch=-5&sensor=false&key=AIzfaNJyAak4_N4g0NaX-2LBqh2w3irnHZTtKJ2xKA'>");
                //add features to map

                var featureLayer = new FeatureLayer("https://services5.arcgis.com/ROBnTHSNjoZ2Wm1P/arcgis/rest/services/Parcels/FeatureServer/0", {
                    mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_ONDEMAND,
                    outFields: ["APN", "BOOK", "PAGE", "SitusAddress", "Imps", "YearBuilt"],
                    infoTemplate: template});
```

This what the site looks like when I click on a feature to bring up it's info including the APN:

[image]

If I paste the link text from here it takes me to this site:

[image]

But if I click it,it directs me here:

```
file:///C:/Users/jsobryan/OneDrive/Desktop/%3Cb
```

And I get the generic file not found message.

Oddly, when I paste it, the end of the b tag is converted to %3b
In the browser I see:

```
file:///C:/Users/jsobryan/OneDrive/Desktop/<b
```

Comment: href= **<b>** www.acgov.org... **</b>** you have tag in link.

Comment: `<a href="http://www.acgov.org/MS/prop/index.aspx?PRINT_PARCEL=${APN}"><b>View On Map</b></a>`

Comment: @Altmish-E-Azam that was part of the issue but I needed to add the http to get directed to the right place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a tag in the link and the link should start with "http://" to show that it is in a different domain.

Comment: That worked. I'd like it to open in another tab but I will hunt around for that bit of code and come back here if I can't find it. Thanks!

Comment: got it. target='blank' at the end of he url string before the closing tag